# How to write Windows 7 gadget in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-desktop-gadgets

How can I use C# to write a gadget in Windows 7?

Is it possible?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate question. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285715/create-windows-desktop-gadget.

Comment: It is not a duplicate. This asks how to do it in C#. Sidebar Gadgets only "support" JavaScript/HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/gadgets/CPRepWindowsGadget.aspx

And a search on codeproject shows even more: http://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=gadget&sbo=kw

Comment: Sidebar Gadgets only "support" JavaScript/HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Is Sidebar gadgets what you are looking for?

Have a [look at this Silverlight trick!](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bf347eb6-99bd-4c99-89d0-6ca3fe1eb54e)

Comment: Sidebar Gadgets only "support" JavaScript/HTML.

Comment: This uses Silverlight hosted in an IFrame I think. So still C#

Comment: The 2nd link does show the Silverlight solution, the first didn't seem relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "Windows Sidebar Gadgets" are being talked about, *this is not possible to do directly*. However there are some work-abouts (none of which are supported by Microsoft):

1. [Use Silverlight](http://www.lazarciuc.ro/ioan/2008/08/02/creating-a-vista-sidebar-gadget-using-microsoft-silverlight/). However, as I recall, the background can't be "painted transparent" and this will *not work* with a 64-bit IE (the IE running gadgets isn't always 32-bit by default) as there is no 64-bit Silverlight. This is the same problem plaguing sidebar gadgets that use Flash. (Like Pandora, one could require avid users to launch the 32-bit version of sidebar.exe).
2. Wrap the gadget window. I started work on a project like this that allowed WPF (in a separate process) to "overlay" the gadget window -- started via COM. Avoids 32/64-bit issues (actually, doesn't matter since it's in a separate process and is CLR, not Silverlight). Some issues with default gadget border, sizing, properties, etc. Concept work only.
3. Use an embedded [HTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331193/executing-32bit-and-64bit-mshta-exe-bypass-default-handler) to launch a 32-bit IE and grab that handle (can then use/embedd Silverlight if launched the 32-bit version). I didn't have success with this, but it "should work".
4. Use a converter like [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp) -- write in C#, "compile" to JavaScript.

Happy coding.